# Using the batch command %random% to get to a random spot on the file

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to use the `%random%` command to go to a random spot on the batch file? For example:

```
set /p input=%random%
if %input%==[whatever the random number generated... (example 1004] goto a
if %input%==[a different number generated by %random% (example 203)] goto b
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and there is no need to translate a number into a label. Simply use the random number as the label. Here is a trivial demonstration that randomly selects 1 of 5 GOTO labels:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set /a label=%random% %% 5
goto %label%

:0
echo random 0 abc
exit /b

:1
echo random 1 def
exit /b

:2
echo random 2 ghi
exit /b

:3
echo random 3 jkl
exit /b

:4
echo random 4 mno
exit /b
```

You could use the same technique to CALL a random label instead. Here is a demonstration that makes 10 random CALLs.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 10) do (
  set /a label=!random! %% 5
  call :!label!
)
exit /b

:0
echo random 0 abc
exit /b

:1
echo random 1 def
exit /b

:2
echo random 2 ghi
exit /b

:3
echo random 3 jkl
exit /b

:4
echo random 4 mno
exit /b
```

--Sample output--

```
random 2 ghi
random 4 mno
random 3 jkl
random 2 ghi
random 2 ghi
random 3 jkl
random 1 def
random 4 mno
random 3 jkl
random 1 def
```

Perhaps your script has differerent contexts, and within each context you have random outcomes. Your labels can consist of a context followed by a number.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 10) do (
  set /a A=!random!%%5, B=!random!%%3
  call :A!A!
  call :B!B!
  echo(
)
exit /b

:A0
echo context A random 0 abc
exit /b

:A1
echo context A random 1 def
exit /b

:A2
echo context A random 2 ghi
exit /b

:A3
echo context A random 3 jkl
exit /b

:A4
echo context A random 4 mno
exit /b


:B0
echo context B random 0 xyz
exit /b

:B1
echo context B random 1 123
exit /b

:B2
echo context B random 2 apple orange banana
exit /b
```

-- Sample output--

```
context A random 3 jkl
context B random 0 xyz

context A random 1 def
context B random 1 123

context A random 4 mno
context B random 2 apple orange banana

context A random 2 ghi
context B random 1 123

context A random 1 def
context B random 2 apple orange banana

context A random 3 jkl
context B random 2 apple orange banana

context A random 0 abc
context B random 1 123

context A random 2 ghi
context B random 1 123

context A random 2 ghi
context B random 1 123

context A random 4 mno
context B random 1 123
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, depending on what your view of *a random spot on the batch file* means. The code you provided almost works, here's an updated version:

```
set NUMBER=%random%
if %NUMBER%==1004 goto A
if %NUMBER%==203 goto B

:A
REM Do something
GOTO :EOF

:B
REM Do something else
```

You cannot jump to a *random* spot inside your batch file, but based on a random value, you can go to pre-defined labels. You can even define some rules where you jump to a label `Z` if the random value is between `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /a number=%random% %% 5
goto destination%number%
```

would `goto` one of destination0, destination1, destination2, destination3, destination4 if that's your intent.